# Stuck while using Amazon api (Itemlookup)

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using amazon's itemlookup api to get the details of an book provided the ISBN has been given to it.

I have made an request to Amazon aws with URL as:

http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=access_key&Keywords=0439708184&Operation=ItemSearch&ResponseGroup=ItemAttributes%2COffers&SearchIndex=Books&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2015-03-23T16%3A04%3A21Z&Version=2009-01-06&Signature=hashed_signature

And all I get from above request is :

```
<Message>Your request is missing required parameters. Required parameters include AssociateTag.</Message>
```

Later on, I have generated an AssociateTag for myself and passed it to the the query string but that did not help either. Instead, it gave me another message that "Signature does not match."

```
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.</Message>
```

After adding the associate tag, my query string looks like as:

http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=access_key&Keywords=0439708184&Operation=ItemSearch&ResponseGroup=ItemAttributes%2COffers&SearchIndex=Books&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2015-03-23T16%3A04%3A21Z&Version=2009-01-06&AssociateTag=hemant-20&Signature=hashed_signature

Am I missing anything basic here?

Comment: Two things:
1) Is there any problem using amazon api's on localhosts?
2)I remember that when I created the aws key and secure key, amazon asked me to give the url of the application and I typed which is non-existent.. Does that matter?